# Using Associate Array to Pass Database Information with PHP and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach

**Issue/Question**: I'm using CodeIgniter to build an event calendar, and I have included a sharing option. This option works at a base level, but only displays the users' ID (primary key) in an `<ul>`. This isn't ideal, and I would like to show the users' first and last names in the `<ul>` instead. I thought creating an associative array would work, but I'm receiving funky results. The first and last name echo out as "Array Array" when the page loads, and the URL id comes up as "Array" when you select the "Array Array" link. I'm wondering what is wrong in my logic.

**Funky link generated in view**:

```
Array Array
```

**Funky URL that is linked to "Array Array"**:

```
http://example.com/user/shared/view/Array
```

**Modified Controller**:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Shared extends Common_Auth_Controller {

    private $end_user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->end_user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
        $data['end_user'] = $this->end_user;
        $this->load->vars($data);

        $this->load->model('events_model', 'events');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $title['title'] = 'Shared';

        $this->load->model('shared_model','shared');

        $data['sharers'][] = array(
                                'shared_owner_id' => $this->shared->get($this->end_user->id),
                                'owner_first_name' => $this->shared->get($this->end_user->first_name),
                                'owner_last_name' => $this->shared->get($this->end_user->last_name),
                                );

        $this->load->view('public/head_view', $title);
        $this->load->view('user/header_view');
        $this->load->view('user/shared_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('user/footer_view');
    }
```

**Modified View**:

```
<div class="hide-on-phones">
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($sharers as $key => $value): ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('user/shared/view/'.$value['shared_owner_id']) ?>"><?php echo $value['owner_first_name']." ".$value['owner_last_name'] ?></a></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**Model**:

```
class Shared_model extends crud_model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->pk = 'id';
        $this->table_name = 'shared';
    }

    public function get($shared_to_user_id)
    {
        $this->db->where('shared_to_id', $shared_to_user_id);
        $ids = parent::get_all();

        $users = array();

        foreach ($ids as $id)
        {

            $users[] = $id->owner_id;
        }

        return $users;
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help, and let me know if there is any more information that may be required. Below are the original view and controllers that work, but are not preferable.

**Original Controller**:

```
public function index()
    {

            $title['title'] = 'Shared';

            $this->load->model('shared_model','shared');

            $data['sharers'] = $this->shared->get($this->end_user->id);

            $this->load->view('user/head_view', $title);
            $this->load->view('user/header_view');
            $this->load->view('user/navigation_view');
            $this->load->view('user/shared_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('user/footer_view');
    }
```

**Original View**:

```
<?php foreach($sharers as $s): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('user/shared/mobile/'.$s) ?>"><?php echo $s ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm new to web development, and I suck at associative arrays (apparently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. I needed to create an associative array in my model; not my controller. Thanks to everyone for your help!

**Model**:

```
class Shares_model extends crud_model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->pk = 'id';
        $this->table_name = 'shares';
    }

    public function get($shared_to_user_id)
    {
        $this->db->where('shared_to_id', $shared_to_user_id);
        $ids = parent::get_all();

        $users = array();

        foreach ($ids as $id)
        {
            $users[$id->owner_id]['owner_id'] = $id->owner_id;
            $users[$id->owner_id]['owner_first_name'] = $id->owner_first_name;
            $users[$id->owner_id]['owner_last_name'] = $id->owner_last_name;
        }

        return $users;
    }   
}
```

**View**:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($sharers as $s): ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('user/shared/view/'.$s['owner_id']) ?>"><?php echo $s['owner_first_name']." ".$s['owner_last_name'] ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

**Controller**:

```
public function index()
    {
        $title['title'] = 'Shared';

        $this->load->model('shares_model','shares');

        $data['sharers'] = $this->shares->get($this->end_user->id);

        $this->load->view('public/head_view', $title);
        $this->load->view('user/header_view');
        $this->load->view('user/shared_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('user/footer_view');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `$data['sharers']` array doesn't have arrays as `$values`. Therefore, the way you are calling the `$value[]'s` in your `foreach` aren't working. You have no reason for calling the `foreach` at this point.

```
<div class="hide-on-phones">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="<?=base_url('user/shared/view/'.$sharers['shared_pk_id'])?>">
           <?=$sharers['first_name'] . ' ' . $sharers['last_name']?>
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I expect you will later on fill an array with the data, in which case you can fill it as

```
$data['sharers'][] = array( 
                            'shared_pk' => $this->shared->get($this->end_user->id),
                            'first_name' => $this->events->get($this->end_user->first_name),
                            'last_name' => $this->events->get($this->end_user->last_name)
                            );
```

Which, in turn can be looped using

```
<div class="hide-on-phones">
  <ul>
    <? foreach($sharers as $sharer): ?>
    <li>
      <a href="<?=base_url('user/shared/view/' . $sharer['shared_pk'])?>">
        <?=$sharer['first_name'] . ' ' . $sharer['last_name']?>
      </a>
    </li>
    <? endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Irussell810 Multiple IDs only, or multiple entries? If you're going for multiple entries, the 2nd and last block of code of my comment should work for you. If it does not, please post again.

Comment: "It doesnt work" won't help me solving this, though. What error is it generating?

Comment: Those notices are generated because the array-values were not set. You can test if those are errors from the view or controller by putting this array in your controller before calling the view `$data['sharers'][] = array('shared_pk_id' => 9000, 'first_name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Doe');`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6042/discussion-between-tyil-and-lrussell810)

Comment: I've updated my question to better explain what I need, what I've done, what I'm doing, and display clearer resources. I hope this helps, and thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

If we take your `$data['sharers']` array and put in values for the php, then we would get something like this:

```
$data['sharers'] = array(
  0 => array(
    'id' => 1234,
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe'
  ),
  1 => array(
    'id' => 1235,
    'first_name' => 'Jane',
    'last_name' => 'Doe'
  )
);
```

So, when you loop through this in your view, you need to access these correctly:

```
foreach($sharers as $key => $value):
    // at this point, in the first iteration of the loop
    // $key is 'id', or 'first_name', or 'last_name'
    // and $value is 1234, or 'John', or 'Doe'
endforeach;
```

So, to loop through the sharers a bit easier, you just need to update your foreach a bit. At this point, change your view to this:

```
<div class="hide-on-phones">
  <ul>
    <?php foreach($sharers as $sharer): ?>
      <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('user/shared/view/'.$sharer['shared_pk_id']) ?>">
          <?php echo $sharer['first_name']. " " .$sharer['last_name'] ?>
        </a>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In that case, look at my edits on the answer. This should help!

Comment: I've updated my question to better explain what I need, what I've done, what I'm doing, and display clearer resources. I hope this helps, and thanks a bunch!